# Is there a way to change Gif speed

Tags: java, gif

I would like to try saving saving at a gifspeed, possibly bring up a box with speed selections, although i'm not quite sure how to change a gif speed using java.

I've looked this up but to no avail. I'm new so I'm sorry if this is a question and I just didn't find it

```
import base.AnimationExporter;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import settings.GuiDrawer;

public class SaveButton extends GuiElement
{
  public SaveButton(GuiMenu parent)
  {
    super(parent);
  }

  public void releasedOn(int posX, int posY, int button)
  {
    if (heldDown) {
      heldDown = false;
      AnimationExporter.saveAnimation(true);
    }
  }

}
```

Edit: My bad heres AnimationExporter

````
   try {
     ImageWriter gifWriter = (ImageWriter)ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif").next();
     ImageOutputStream outputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputFile);
     gifWriter.setOutput(outputStream);

     ImageTypeSpecifier imageType = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(2);
     IIOMetadata metadata = gifWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageType, null);
     IIOMetadataNode nodeTree = (IIOMetadataNode)metadata.getAsTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());

     IIOMetadataNode appExtensionsNode = getNode("ApplicationExtensions", nodeTree);
     IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");
     child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
     child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");

     child.setUserObject(new byte[] { 1, (byte)((Editing.animationLoop ? 0 : 1) & 0xFF), (byte)((Editing.animationLoop ? 0 : 1) >> 8 & 0xFF) });
     appExtensionsNode.appendChild(child);

     metadata.setFromTree(metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName(), nodeTree);

     gifWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
     for (Frame frame : animation.Animation.frames) {
       IIOMetadata imageMetadata = gifWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageType, null);
       IIOMetadataNode imageNodeTree = (IIOMetadataNode)imageMetadata.getAsTree(imageMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName());
       IIOMetadataNode graphicNode = getNode("GraphicControlExtension", imageNodeTree);
       graphicNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
       graphicNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
       graphicNode.setAttribute("delayTime", Integer.toString(delay));

       imageMetadata.setFromTree(imageMetadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName(), imageNodeTree);

       IIOImage currentImage = new IIOImage(frame.getEntireFrame(), null, imageMetadata);
       gifWriter.writeToSequence(currentImage, null);
     }
     gifWriter.endWriteSequence();
     outputStream.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }```
````

Comment: Neither `base.AnimationExporter` nor `settings.GuiDrawer` are Java API classes and their package names are nondescriptive, so we don't know what they are.  Hence it's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Please post your code as an [mcve] that we can use to reproduce your problem. The code that you have posted is incomplete but also contains many irrelevant parts. That said - what is `delayTime` in this line ` graphicNode.setAttribute("delayTime", Integer.toString(delay));`? That seems to be the crux here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, so sorry I thought I had less copied down,l ooking at it now I feel dumb, `delayTime` here is,

`public int delay = Editing.frameDelay;`
I assume `frameDelay` is what I should change
`public static int frameDelay = 100;`

Answer (score 0):

The framerate of the 'GIF' is embedded. However, you can speed it up or slow it down through external tools. Photoshop may work best. [This](https://ezgif.com/speed) tool may be able to help you. If you need dynamic framerate changes we need more information on the libraries you are using.